# How to api integeration in core php

Tags: php, api

I had the payment integration with paywithcapure. They send the sample code for test i used that code its 404 error.

```
    $xml_data2 = 'merchantid=somevalue&token=somevalue&bvn=somevalue';
    $URL = "http://flutterwavestaging.com:8080/FlutterwaveRecurringPayments/services/flwcardrecurring/VerifyBvn";
    $ch = curl_init($URL);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content type - application/x-www-urlencoded'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_data2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

First make sure that url is working fine.Paste your url in browser and see the result.If it's not working then contact them for correct url and if its working fine then try this code :

```
$xml_data2 = 'merchantid=somevalue&token=somevalue&bvn=somevalue';
    $URL = "http://flutterwavestaging.com:8080/FlutterwaveRecurringPayments/services/flwcardrecurring/VerifyBvn";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $URL); // you've missed this one.
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MUTE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content type - application/x-www-urlencoded'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_data2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply mr.enginner.

But same problem arise

Comment: But they provide that URL for as testing

Comment: Just paste that url in browser and see the result.

Comment: Ya Mr.Engineer its show 404 error. 
can you share the code for rest client like postman. can you post code for that?

Comment: No. Bcoz if url is not working then i cant do anything with it.But you can read document for it on their site if any.

Comment: nothing leave it friend. Thanks for your support. We create a ticket for support team in API